# Accessing vector<vector<char> > elements as rows and columns

Tags: c++, vector, matrix, std

I am trying to use a

```
vector<vector<char> > matrix;
```

as an actual matrix.

matrix is initialized with all '\0' and it gets filled in during the process.

let's imagine at a certain point of time I am in this situation:

```
     0   1  2  3
  0  a   b  c \0
  1  b   b \0 \0
  2  c  \0 \0 \0
  3  \0 \0 \0 \0
```

if I want to have a char * to the first row I can do a:

```
&word_square[0][0]
```

that will give me a pointer to the first row, pointer that I can use as a C char array  (ie. "abc")

What if I want to get the first column in the same way?
Is it possible or I'll have to do it with a for?

```
int i =0;
string column;
while(matrix[i][0] != '\0' )
{
  column.push_back(matrix[i][0]);
  i++;
}
```

I would love to get a cleaner solution as I did above for the row.
initializing a string just for getting the column I need and I already have it's not so nice. Moreover it slows down my process.

Many thanks to those who will help.

Comment: in C++ is there any way I could do what I am trying to do there without the copy overhead?

Answer (score 4):

Using a `vector< vector<char> >`, you have no guarantee that the inner vectors store their data contiguously in memory, meaning there is no possible way to have a `char*` that points to the elements in column order unless you manually copy the data.

Comment: ok thanks. Too bad that I'll need the overhead of copy for getting the columns.Concerning the rows is it ok the way I use them?

Comment: Yes, you are guaranteed that the chars for one vector are stored contiguously in memory, or you can even just do `word_square[0].data()`

Comment: thanks, and do you have any idea on how I could do it for columns as well? maybe using some other data structure?

Comment: There really isn't a way to do it without copying as you basically want to have your cake and eat it too by having the characters stored in both row order and column order simultaneously.

Answer (score 2):

You can [slice a std::valarray](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/valarray/slice/) to do something along the lines of what you're interested in doing.  They use contiguous memory, and the slice manages access to the original data object, so there's no copying involved.

Answer (score 1):

Impossible with a vector of vectors. Your best bet is to write your own class that returns proxy objects.